# Upload array of Objects Firestore swift

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, upload

ich work with swift and firestore and try to implemented a server similar to this:

```
    chatId: String
    eventCreatorId: String
    matchedUserId: String
    eventId: String
    messages: [
    {userId: String, timestamp:timestamp, messageText: String},
    {userId: String, timestamp:timestamp, messageText: String},
  ],
```

in other Words with a MVVM design i want to upload a array of Models
but i getting a type error when i try with this

```
struct ChatModel: Codable {
    var chatId: String
    var eventCreatorId: String
    var matchedUserId: String
    var eventId: String
    var messages: [MessageModel]

}

struct MessageModel: Codable {
    var userId: String
    var timeStamp: Timestamp
    var messageText: String
    
}
```

the error happens if i try to upload

```
    func uploadMessage(messageText: String, chatId: String) -> Promise<Void> {
        return Promise { seal in
            guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
                return
            }
            let timeStamp: Timestamp = Timestamp(date: Date())
            let messageModel = MessageModel(userId: currentUser.uid,timestamp: timeStamp, messageText: messageText)
            print(messageModel)
                let _ = db.collection("chats")
                    .document(chatId)
                    .updateData(["messages" : FieldValue.arrayUnion([messageModel])]) { error in
                        if let error = error {
                            seal.reject(error)
                        } else {
                            seal.fulfill(())
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

i tried also without the timestamp but ran into the same error

can someone explain me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you seeing? Is it a Swift syntax error or an error from Firebase after you make a call?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported type: __SwiftValue'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: i think that is a firebase error, that firebase didn´t know the type

Comment: Where does that happen? You're not showing the code that would actually lead to that error

Comment: sorry i was thinking my mistakes were in the model arichtecture, i added the upload function to my question

Comment: I don't believe you can use a custom object inside updateData and FieldValue.arrayUnion like that. I'm not going to leave it as an answer because maybe someone more knowledgeable will chime in, but my guess is you will have to convert your objects to [String:Any] first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On ArrayUnion, Firestore does not understand the type you're trying to pass.
Converting the struct to a dictionary with type [String: Any] will ommit this error -

```
struct MessageModel: Codable {
    var userId: String
    var timeStamp: Timestamp
    var messageText: String
    
    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        return["userId": userId,
               "timeStamp": timeStamp,
               "messageText": messageText]
    }
}
```

Then when you're uploading to Firestore you use the Dict value:

```
 .updateData(["messages" : FieldValue.arrayUnion([messageModel.dictionary])]) { error in
```